# How to move cursor to a C++ function(method)'s name from its body in VSCode with VIM extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vim, vscodevim

I'm developing some C++ code with VSCode+VIM extension. From time to time I need to do this while reading code: say I'm inside a long function and I want to know who called it. The first step to do is to move cursor directly under function's name so that I can invoke some keystrokes to show references.

What I'm current using is to press "[" key twice which will bring me to the opening bracket of the function. Since I have to follow some coding standard, the typical scenario is like this:

```
ReturnType ClassName::FunctionName(
    ParamType1 param1,
    ParamType2 param2,
    ParamType3 param3)
{ // <-- Cursor here
    ......

}
```

Then I need to press "k" several times to move cursor under "ReturnType", depending on how many parameters are there. Next, I still have to press "w" 3 times to eventually move cursor from "ReturnType", to "FunctionName".

As you can see, this is a little painful here. I've tried easy motion approach with VSCode VIM extension, this makes my life a little easier, but I'm looking for a even better one.

Any VIM trick or VSCode extension can do this decently?
Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: This is a question about using a tool programme uses so it should be on topic...

Comment: Perhaps `[[b%b`.

Comment: Thank you, @user202729, [[b%b seems working except when the function has a empty signature. So [[ge%b will work.

Comment: That having said it might be easier to get an answer on the other site https://vi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid having to press `k` a variable number of times it's possible to make use of the fact that the `)` is right on the line above, and use `%` to go to the matching `(`. The complete key sequence is `[[b%b`.

However the first `b` will go to the `(` if there's nothing between the parentheses. `[[ge%b` can be used instead.

If there's something between `)` and `{` (such as a `const` qualifier) `[[?)<cr>%b` would work (this solution is complex and perhaps only useful in a key binding?)

`[[?(<cr>b` works too as long as there's no parameter that contains an open parentheses (such as in `FunctionName(int (*function_pointer)(int, int)) { ... }`)

Comment: (Depends on the particular plugin, it might also be possible to view the list of callers without moving the pointer.)